# Como pegar a row selecionada jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

tenho meu grid:

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
    var grid = $("#gridGrupo").dataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "/Scripts/Libs/DataTables/ptBr.txt"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/grupo/data",
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Id" },
            { "data": "Nome", },
            { "data": "Descricao" }
        ]
    });
    $('#gridGrupo tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('row_selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        }
        else {
            grid.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }
    });
```

Ele seta a classe "row_selected" quando ele seleciona uma linha

Eu tenho a minha função

```
function Editar(){
}
```

Preciso pegar a linha que ele selecionou, que tem a classe "row_selectd" para pegar o Id, e se não encontrar, mandar uma msg

Não estou conseguindo a parte de selecionar o Id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pelo que vi aqui é simples

utilizando o seguinte comando para remover a linha podendo ser adaptado:

```
$('#button').click( function () {
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
    } );
```

Caso precise de mais ajuda suba essa parte no jsfiddle para ajudar um pouco mais